# Difficulties with mathematical induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I understand the concept of mathematical induction. Its towards the end where i feel that im missing something.

Problem: Prove that $4^n=(4(4^n-16))/3$     for $n\le 3$.

I have that the base case is true.

Next I assume $4^k=(4(4^k-16))/3$ is true.

Then I prove if it is true for $n=k$ then its true for $n=k+1$.

So,
\begin{array}{ll}
4^k+1 &=(4(4^k+1-16))/3    \\
     4^k (4) & =(4(4^k+1-16))/3 \\
\end{array}
LHS  $4(4^k-16))/3 \cdot 4$       since it was assumed that
$$4^k=(4(4^k-16))/3  =(4^k+1-64)/3 \cdot 4=(4^k+1-256)/3.$$

I do not understand what I am missing.

Comment: Something funny is happening. Traditionally, induction works with increasing powers of $n$. So, given the statement "for $n \leq 3$", the only sensible way to use induction would be to prove this for _descending_ powers of $n$ (starting with base case $n=3$), which seems odd.

Answer (score 4):

Your statement is not true.  For $n=2$ you are claiming $16=4^2=(4(4^2-16))/3=0$  In fact it is not true for $1$ either-the left side is positive and the right is negative.

Maybe what you want is $4^n=4(4^n-4^{n-1})/3$, which you can prove without induction.

Answer (score 0):

pjs36 is right, and so is Ross.

To answer the "induction process" for divisibility questions, one would assume statement is true for $n=k$ and prove the next case, which in this problem is $n=k-1$.

To answer divisible type questions I  usually write:

Assume true for $n=k$, i.e. $4^k=4(4^k-16) = 3m$ where $m$ is some integer.

To prove for the next case ($k-1$), we simply need to show that $m$ is a factor.

Ie when $n=k-1$, we are trying to prove that $4^{k-1}$ is also divisible by 3.

So,

\begin{align}
4^{k-1} & = 4(4^{k-1}-16) \\
 & = 4(4^{k}.4^{-1}  - 16) \\ 
 & = 4^{k}  - 48 \\
 & = 3m  - 3\times16 \\ 
 & = 3(m-16) \end{align} which is divisible by 3

But... remember that to prove induction, you show the first case is true...

Ie test for $n=k$. As Ross has indicated, the formula doesn't hold true! The test of the first case is $4^3$ = 64, but $4(4^3-16) = 192$, which is not true, so the induction process fails!

Having said this, the induction method would work if we had a correct LHS.